# Regex that matches beginning and end

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to find a regex that matches words that start with ch and end in jane. The program I am searching in is java-based, so that may be why none of the things I've tried so far worked for me??? I know that there are already threads with the same topic, but I couldn't resolve my problem so far.

I have tried so far:

```
/^ch\..*jane$/

^ch\..*jane$

\bch\.\w+jane\b
```

and some related to that (trial and error...) that do not give me any results at all.

There are two that work:

```
\bch.*jane\b 

^ch(.*)jane$
```

but they give me more results than I want, i.e., but a string of words where the first one starts in ch and the last one ends in jane in addition to single words staring with ch and ending in jane. I am looking for single words only!

Can any of you help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want beginning of the string or word boundary?

Word boundary you use `\bmyregex-word\b`, there shall not be any spaces and `^my.*regex$` matches the entire string such that if the string dies not start with `my` and ends with `regex`, it will always fail to match

Now to find `words` use: `\bch\w*jane\b`

Comment: If an answer helped you marked it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below regex to match the words which starts with `ch` and ends with `jane`,

```
(?=^ch.*)(?=.*jane$).*
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/bZ3eJ9/1)

Comment: it won't work if the string chjane is present in the middle of a line.